# How does gsub work with '*', '+' and '?'

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"111".gsub(/1?/, "2")
 => "2222" 

"111".gsub(/1/, "2")
 => "222"

"111".gsub(/1*/, "2")
 => "22"

"111".gsub(/1+/, "2")
 => "2"
```

Why, and how, does it work like above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first regexp matches 4 times: once on each `1`, and once on the *empty string* at the end.

The second regexp matches 3 times, only for the `1`s.

The third regexp matches once for `111` (greedy!) and once for the *empty string* at the end (`*` says optional, so the empty string matches, too!)

The fourth regexp greedly takes the full string, matches only once in total. The end does not match, as there is no (required) `1` left anymore.

You should look up the notion of **greedy matching** with regular expressions. Here are some more for you to try: `/1*?/` and `/1+?/`. Figure out why these match as they do for yourself!

Comment: Why the empty string at the end can be matched, but couldn't the one at the beginning?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan: Because `*` (and friends) greedily eat as many characters as possible. If it could match either '' or '1', it will choose '1'. Try `"3111".gsub(/1?/, '2')` and you will see it matches the empty string at the begin as well.

Comment: And why, `/1/` can match 3 times, but `/1+?/` doesn't match `1`, `1`, `1` respectively?

Comment: Also try matching "" with each of the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

After each successful match, the part of string after the match is scanned for more matches. This is even done for an empty string (if it is not already part of the previous match).

Note also that `?`, `*` and `+` always match as many characters as possible ("greedy").

In detail:

```
"111".gsub(/1?/, "2")
```

The first `1` matches -> one `2`, the second and the third `1` result in two more `2`s.
Then the empty string matches, resulting in one more `2`.

```
"111".gsub(/1/, "2")
```

This is obvious.

```
"111".gsub(/1*/, "2")
```

`111` matches resulting in one `2`. Then, the empty string matches resulting in one more `2`.

```
"111".gsub(/1+/, "2")
```

`111` matches -> one `2`. The empty string does not match, no more `2`.